# Javascript (break)

Tags: javascript

Im in the process of learning javascript and I cant seem to understand why the break statement isnt functioning :( Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong?

```js
let maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the maximum number")); 
while(!maximum){ 
    maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter a valid number")); 
}
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1; 
console.log(randomNum);
let guess = parseInt(prompt(`Enter your guess for the generated number between 1 and the maximum number of ${maximum}.`));
let attempts = 1;

while (parseInt(guess) !== randomNum){
    if (guess === 'q') break;
    attempts++;
    if(guess > randomNum){
        guess = prompt("Too high, guess again.");
    } else{
        guess = prompt("Too low, guess again.");
    }
}
if (guess === 'q'){
    console.log("Quitting.")
} else {
console.log(`It took you ${attempts} amounts of guesses!`)
}
```

Comment: _"why the break statement isnt functioning"_ - what is the expected behavior? What's the current behavior? I think problem is because of `guess === 'q'`; using `===` will return true only if their types are same; in your case, `guess` is a number and `'q'` is a string

Comment: I think the break should be in a newline with atleast 2 space indentation

Comment: It does not work if you press `q` on the first attempt to guess because of `let guess = parseInt(prompt(...));`. The call to `parseInt()` makes `guess` contain a number and a number cannot be equal to the string `'q'`. It works fine starting from the second attempt.

Comment: @GhostOps no, the formatting is irrelevant in JS.

Comment: Please change the title of your question. It has nothing to do with the `break` statement, but with the way `parseInt` works.

Comment: @kuroineko OP's question regarding the `break` statement not working as expected by the OP. If OP knew that problem is because of `parseInt`, OP wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: And how many people do you think a title like "Javascript (break)" could potentially help? Might as well change it to "please debug my code"...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (guess === 'q')
```

You are parsing the value to an integer and are comparing it to a string. Which is always false

So when you type 'q' in your prompt and try parseInt on it you will get NaN which stands for not a number. And NaN is not equal with q obviously

EDIT:

as @axic correctly pointed out the condition from above cannot be fulfilled if q was typed before the iteration begins. But that brings another problem:
On the third iteration you will get another prompt saying "Too low, guess again." even if you guessed the right number, because guess is string and compared to a number which will return false in all cases.

Comment: Does this mean I need to get rid of the parseInt? What should i do to ensure the user input is converted to an int yet q isnt converted to an int?

Comment: To build on top of this answer, assuming you keep `guess` as a string, why would you use a `break` statement, anyway, instead of adding the exit condition directly in `while (parseInt(guess) !== randomNum && guess !== 'q')`

Comment: @smailwail You need to remove the `parseInt` call from the `parseInt(prompt(\`Enter your guess for the...`

Comment: You can at first check if there is a number as input with isNaN(guess). When there is a number, do the number work, otherwise check if guess === 'q'

Comment: The condition cannot be fulfilled on the first iteration no matter the input but it can be fulfilled on the subsequent iterations. This answer is misleading.

Comment: @smailwail there are many ways to skin a cat, a a general rule of thumb, when dealing with real-life projects, it is a good idea to follow the approach that you better understand because it makes it easier to you to debug and maintain the code in the future

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the value to an integer and are comparing it to a string.

```js
let maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter the maximum number"));
while (!maximum) {
  maximum = parseInt(prompt("Enter a valid number"));
}
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1;
console.log(randomNum);
let guess = prompt(`Enter your guess for the generated number between 1 and the maximum number of ${maximum}.`);
let attempts = 1;

while (parseInt(guess) !== randomNum) {
  if (guess === 'q') break;
  attempts++;
  if (guess > randomNum) {
    guess = prompt("Too high, guess again.");
  } else {
    guess = prompt("Too low, guess again.");
  }
}
if (guess === 'q') {
  console.log("Quitting.")
} else {
  console.log(`It took you ${attempts} amounts of guesses!`)
}
```

Comment: @smailwail please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The break statement works totally fine, the issue is in a different location of your logic. You are parsing the integer of guess when displaying the first prompt to enter a guess for the number but when entering anything that isn't a number the value will simply be NaN.

Line 7 is:

```js
let guess = parseInt(prompt(`Enter your guess for the generated number between 1 and the maximum number of ${maximum}.`));
```

but should be:

```js
let guess = prompt(`Enter your guess for the generated number between 1 and the maximum number of ${maximum}.`);
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want to achieve but based on the little information you gave I assumed that this would be what you're trying to get.